# One question about derivation of Maxwell equations

Tags: electromagnetism, special-relativity, maxwell-equations

I saw the following way of derivation of Maxwell equations: author starts from Lorentz transformations for the 3-vector of force, then he applies them for the Coulomb law, after that gets the Lorentz force law with expressions for $\mathbf E $ and for $\mathbf B$ fields, then he takes curl and divergence and, finally, he derives the Maxwell equation for the field of charge moving with constant speed.

After that he uses a few axioms: superposition principle and independence of equations on acceleration, and generalizes equations on all electrodynamical processes.

But I have some doubts about this method. The most problematic question is followIng: there are EM fields of electric and magnetic type. For the first one $\mathbf E^{2} - \mathbf B^{2} > 0$, for the second one - $\mathbf E^{2} - \mathbf B^{2} < 0$. But the author have started from the electric type, so he can't generalize final result on all EM processes.

The question: can we violate this argument against this methot of derivation by introducing some other argument?

Comment: It would be helpful if you could supply us with a reference to the derivation you mentioned.

Comment: You are right in the sense that this way you cannot obtain all possible EM fields. There is another (pseudo)invariant ${\mathbf E}\cdot \mathbf B$. If $\mathbf B=0$ in a reference frame in any other reference frame is absent or normal to $\mathbf E$. However you says that the author is interested in finding **Maxwell equations** not all their solutions, so  the procedure could make sense.

Comment: Could you please post the derivation or a link to it? The Coulomb law and the Lorentz transformations are not sufficient to derive Maxwell's equations.

Comment: @JánLalinský : are you interested in derivation the expression of the Lorentz force or in derivation of Maxwell equations by given $\mathbf E, \mathbf B$ from the expression of the Lorentz force?

Comment: Mainly, the derivation of Maxwell's equations you mentioned. But the derivation of the Lorentz force expression may be interesting as well.